# All the F# templates in VS 2015 RC disappear

Tags: templates, f#, visual-studio-2015

I installed in a fresh Win 8.1 machine VS 2015 RC. I load VS and create a F# project. Fine.

Eventually, I do some other stuff (that I have not remember) and then I found that no single F# template (for projects) exist anymore in VS. Only C#/VB ones.

Comment: Have your tried repairing Visual Studio 2015RC?

Comment: I have tried that but not work.

Comment: What is the framework version selected in the new project window?

Comment: First was 4.5.2. I change to the others and still not see the F# templates. I install from the web the ASPNET MVC F# template, it show, but NONE of the defaults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug in 2015 RC. It's already fixed, but we need to wait for another release.
https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/411